# Est-ce que l'expression "tout type" est écrite correctement ?

Tags: pluriel, accord

Je souhaite savoir si l'expression "tout type" est écrite correctement dans la phrase suivante ? Est-ce qu'elle s'accorde et pourquoi ?

> Les algorithmes de segmentation sont-ils performants sur tout type de tumeurs ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C'est suivant le sens que tu veux donner (suivant le contexte l'un peut être le seul possible ou la différence être imperceptible):

- *tout type* signifie *n'importe quel type*
- *tous types* signifie *tous les types*

Il me semble que l'usage a tendance à préférer le singulier quand la nuance n'est pas forte.

Answer (score 3):

C'est au choix, singulier ou pluriel :

> Les algorithmes de segmentation sont-ils performants sur tout type de tumeur ?
>   Les algorithmes de segmentation sont-ils performants sur tous les types de tumeurs ?

La première version est d'un emploi un peu plus général, voire abstrait, alors que la seconde prétend par l'article défini identifier tous les types de tumeurs envisageables.